# Compare points in two grids

Tags: javascript, swift, math

I have two raster with x points on it like this:

[image]

I have this data from each raster in a array like this:

```
[
[200,330],
[500,800]
]
```

How can i compare this data to figure out how many percent as equal this both grids to each other?

My idea is to generate a hash and compare this both hashes, but i don't have an idea how can i do this.

This idea comes from audio fingerprinting.

I will do this in swift or javascript.

Thanks you for each thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to compute the **similarity** between two vectors.
In your case the vector looks like: [[x1,y1], [x2,y2], ...,[xn, yn]]

I would recommend [Cosine Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).
The implementation is pretty straight forward, regardless the programming language.

*(There are existing implementation of Cosine Similarity out there, for example [In JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/robertknight/5410420))*